# Why phpstorm don't beautify HTML code?

Tags: ide, html, editor

I have a list

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
</ul>
```

When I press code/reformat code in menu, nothing not happened?
But this action work for PHP or JavaScript file.
How to make the editor format HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `<ul>` and `<li>` are not listed in `Settings/Editor/Code Style/HTML/Other/Do not indent children of` option.